# change url & pass values using by react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to change path and pass values when clicked ok button.
And I'm using TypeScript & React..
My situations is when using history state it causes ts error..
Any other option what I want..

```js
      <Modal
        title={notice?.title}
        visible={isNotice}
        onCancel={onClose}
        onOk={() => history.push({pathname:PATH.CUSTOMER_CENTER__NOTICE, state:notice?.contentId})}
      >
```

```js
  const history = useHistory();

  const historyKey = useMemo(() => {
    if (history) {
      return setKey(history.location.state);
    }
    return 0;
  }, [history]);

...
...

return (

    <Collapse
      defaultActiveKey={defaultActiveKey}
      bordered={false}
      accordion
      activeKey={history.location.state}
    >
...
```

and I can't setState and use value of Collapse property..

I got this error,,
property) History<History.PoorMansUnknown>.location: Location<History.PoorMansUnknown>
Argument of type 'PoorMansUnknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number | null | undefined>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number | null | undefined>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type '(prevState: number | null | undefined) => number | null | undefined'.
Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: number | null | undefined): number | null | undefined'

How should I do if I want change url and also pass value for Collapse property.

Comment: try change `onOk` to `onClick`

Comment: @VadimHulevich I'm using antd Library So there is no property of onClick. And I think it work same.

Comment: so you need check what inside, try `console.log` and show what you get

Comment: I got history Object which is react router Object